# Is there a way to submit a "fake" form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

What I want to do is make a POST request with arbitrary params, much like submitting a form. That is **not merely doing the XHR**. What I ideally want is to emulate a submit (like submiting a form, not POSTiing and then redirecting). I want to avoid the latency of $.post + window.top.location = blah

The most direct way would be to have a 'fake' form and insert a bunch of elements, then serialize and use jQuery.submit(), something like [Is there a way using jQuery to submit a form without the elaborate field by field breakdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292486/is-there-a-way-using-jquery-to-submit-a-form-without-the-elaborate-field-by-fiel)

I wish there were a more elegant way.

My use case is that I am gathering a bunch of random fields through external API calls (from Facebook and other services) and want to submit ALL that info at once to user creation, as if the user filled out all this information and pressed 'submit'

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

yes

you can use $.ajax ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/s4fau/1/))

or $.post and $.get ... example:

```
$.post(
          "url_to_page",
          /* string like this: "text=me%20man&mail=peace@man.com or an object": */
          {text: "me man", mail: "peace@man.com"}
      )
      /* you can check if the request was submitted successfully */
      .success(function(data) {
          alert("Success!");
          alert(data); //data on page
      })
      /* you can check if the request failed */
      .error(function() {
          alert("Error!");
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is not quite what I am asking though (doing the XHR). What I ideally want is to emulate a submit (like submiting a form, not POSTIing and then redirecting). I want to avoid the latency of $.post + window.top.location = blah

Comment: Just add the redirecting to the success function
`.success(function(data) { window.location.href = "blablabla";})`